# How to make a page "lights out" except for one element

Tags: javascript, html, css, position

I'm not really asking for help with my code, I'm more asking, how do you do this?

When you click my div, the screen goes black, but I want my div underneath to still show as normal, but the rest of the area to be blacked out.

```js
function lightsout() {
  document.getElementById("lightsout").style.visibility = "visible";
}
```

```html
<div style="width:100px;height:100px;border:2px solid blue" onclick="lightsout()">Click Me</div>

<div id="lightsout" style="position:fixed;top:0;left:0;width:100%;height:100%;background-color:black;visibility:hidden;">
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the box-shadow property to achieve this effect.

**Updated the Code**

```js
function lightsout() {
  document.getElementById("maindiv").classList.toggle("visible");
}
```

```css
.visible{
box-shadow: 0 0 0 10000px #000;
position: relative;
}

body{
color: red;
}
```

```html
<div style="width:100px;height:100px;border:2px solid blue; color: #000;" onclick="lightsout()" id="maindiv">Click Me</div>

Other elements on the page will be hidden...
```

Comment: It may not work on bigger screens with 1000px shadow

Comment: @UmairKhalid just give a very very big number per your requirements  :)

Comment: Yup I think it will be perfect if we use 100vw , it will change according to width of screen

Answer (score 1):

You can simply add [`z-indexes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index) to your positioning. With giving the black area a lower z-index than your button but a higher z-index than the rest, you will have your effect.

Also it is recommended to not use inline styles, as your code becomes way more maintainable with styles and markup seperate.

```js
function lightsout() {
  document.getElementById("lightsout").classList.toggle("visible");
}
```

```css
.button {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 2px solid blue;
  background: white;
}

#lightsout {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 5;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: gray;
  visibility: hidden;
}
#lightsout.visible {
  visibility: visible
}
```

```html
<div class="button" onclick="lightsout()">Click Me</div>
<div id="lightsout"></div>

Other elements are hidden.
```

Comment: It will require major change in design

Comment: I just added z-indexes. why is that a major design change?

Comment: Only problem is I'd have to start putting z-index on every single element in the page. (I just used one element for my example)

Comment: No you won't. Initial (unset) z-index is 0.

Answer (score 0):

you can use css,

z-index, and add divbox background-color like this :)

```js
function lightsout() {
  document.getElementById("lightsout").style.visibility = "visible";
}
```

```css
#lightsout{
  z-index: -1
}
```

```html
<div style="width:100px;height:100px;border:2px solid blue;background-color:white;" onclick="lightsout()">Click Me</div>

<div id="lightsout" style="position:fixed;top:0;left:0;width:100%;height:100%;background-color:black;visibility:hidden;">http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42688925/how-to-make-a-page-lights-out-except-for-one-element#
```

Comment: Cool, only problem is it only works where there is only one element on the page. I was trying to keep things simple for the example :-)